# HREF values search through the web page using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am working on 3rd Party application where I can only view to the Webpage source content.And from there I have to collect only some `href` content values which has pattern like `/aems/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId`. Is it possible?

***HTML*** **(Part of HTML)**

```
<td width="50%">
<a href="/aems/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=10597525&cs=9b7sjueBiWLBEMj2ZU4I6fyQoPv-g0NLY9ETqP0gWk4.xyz">
screenshot.doc
</a>
</td>
```

Comment: Check out [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/). You could parse the document for only `href` that match the required pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '
<td width="50%">
<a href="/aems/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=10597525&cs=9b7sjueBiWLBEMj2ZU4I6fyQoPv-g0NLY9ETqP0gWk4.xyz">
screenshot.doc
</a>
</td>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
doc.search('a[href]').map{ |a| a['href'] }
```

Which returns:

```
[
    [0] "/aems/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=10597525&cs=9b7sjueBiWLBEMj2ZU4I6fyQoPv-g0NLY9ETqP0gWk4.xyz"
]
```

If you want to filter for path matches, use something like:

```
pattern = Regexp.escape('/aems/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId')
doc.search('a[href]').map{ |a| a['href'] }.select{ |href| href[ %r[^#{ pattern }] ] }
```

Which, again, returns:

```
[
  [0] "/aems/file/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=10597525&cs=9b7sjueBiWLBEMj2ZU4I6fyQoPv-g0NLY9ETqP0gWk4.xyz"
]
```

This code will return the `href` parameter from all `<a>` tags with `href` in the document. In the second example, it will filter them by the path.

Comment: Here i just pasted part of an `HTML` but in current scenario,i have to pass `URL` onto the browser, and then from that webpage I have to collect such values of `href`. In such a case how should I frame your program?

Comment: You need to write your question as you intend to implement the solutions presented, not partially ask it then change it. As is, your additional comment makes no sense and you need to rephrase the original question to clarify it, explaining how you need it to work. AND, show YOUR work.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'open-uri'
source='http://www.example.com'
page = open(source).read
URI.extract(page,/.*\/aems\/file\/filegetrevision.do?fileEntityId=.*/)
```

Comment: `+1` for your interest to my post.what package i need to install for that @alex?

Comment: The feature is you don't need to install anything. OpenURI is a part of the standart ruby library.